# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django.core'

Tags: python, django

I want to create django project so I've configured virtualenv ,and I installed django `pipenv install django==4.0.1` when  I create app using this command `python3 manage.py startapp Accounts`
I got this error.

```
(env) zakaria@ZAKARIA:/mnt/c/Users/ZAKARIA/Desktop/project$ python manage.py startapp Accounts
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 11, in main
    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django.core'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 13, in main
    raise ImportError(
ImportError: Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you forget to activate a virtual environment?
```

> can any one help to solve this problem ?

Comment: Isn't it `pip install django=4.0.1`? You can use `pip list` to check installed packages

Comment: it's installed in my packages

Comment: @vinkomlacic To install a specific version using pip you do need to use a double equals. I'm not sure about ```pipenv``` though (never used that before).

Comment: @ChaddRobertson True, it was a typo. **EDIT**: `pip install django==4.0.1`

Comment: @vinkomlacic  I am always using pipenv in the same approach and always working i don't Know what's happens

Comment: Looks like you installed Django in a different virtualenv than the one you're running `startapp` from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `python3 manage.py startapp Accounts` try `python manage.py startapp Accounts` with your `venv` activated.

To explain why this matters, let's go through an exercise. Starting without a `venv` activated, try this process (you may need to use the `deactivate` command to turn off if you're in a `venv`:

```
python -m venv my_venv
# The following line assumes you're on Linux or Mac; it appears you're using WSL-2, which is fine
. my_venv/bin/activate
# The following command should show the path to the Python binary in your venv
which python
# The following command may show that you're not hitting the Python version in your venv, but somewhere else
which python3
```

You want to make sure you're using the Python binary that is inside your `venv`. Good luck!

Comment: I Solve this problem , delete this project and restart my computer and create new project it's work,I don't know what's happed

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue when I was connecting Django with Docker. I fix this issue by running this command:

```
docker-compose create --build
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33672116)